# How to return response of array of objects

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, datatables, laravel-5.1

Here is my Response

```
data : [{id: 30, tmb_order_id: "TMB030"}, {id: 33, tmb_order_id: "TMB033"}]
```

Like this pic

[image]

But i want my Response like

```
{
    "data": [
        [
            "30",
            "TMB030"
        ],
        [
            "33",
            "TMB033",
        ],
    ]
}
```

How can i do this ?

Here is the way how i get it in controller

```
$data = Order::where('user_id',$id)->where('status',1)->select('id', 'tmb_order_id')->get();
        $Response = array('data' => $data ); 
        return $Response;
```

What should i do to get the response like that ?

Help pls

Comment: in your controller where you return response change to `echo  json_encode($Response); die();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
$data = Order::where('user_id',$id)->where('status',1)->select('id', 'tmb_order_id')->get();
$alldata = array();
foreach($data as $single){
     $alldata[] = array($single->id, $single->tmb_order_id);
}
$Response = array('data' => $alldata ); 
return json_encode($Response);
```

Answer (score 0):

answering it after some time.

import the Request class then do it:

```
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    public function show(Request $request)
    {
      $data = MyModel::where('id', $request->id)->get();
      return response()->json($data);
    }
```